# Get x y coordinates from a pdf document on click

Tags: c#, itext

I am trying to stamp a text  in a pdf document. For this reason i need to be able to get the coordinates when I click in the pdf document. To stamp the text I am using itextsharp library. How can I get the x,y coordinates and the pdf page number.

this is my code for stamping:

```
public string formatPdf(string sourceFileName, string newFileName, string inputText, float xValue, float yValue)
{ 
    using (Stream pdfStream = new FileStream(sourceFileName, FileMode.Open))
        {
            using (Stream newpdfStream = new FileStream(newFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfStream);
                PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, newpdfStream);
                PdfContentByte pdfContentByte = pdfStamper.GetOverContent(1);
                BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1250, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
                pdfContentByte.SetColorFill(BaseColor.RED);
                pdfContentByte.SetFontAndSize(baseFont, 12);
                pdfContentByte.BeginText();
                pdfContentByte.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, inputText, xValue, yValue, 0);
                pdfContentByte.EndText();
                pdfStamper.Close();
            }
        }

        return newFileName;

}
```

Comment: iTextSharp does not render a PDF. Thus, you cannot click a PDF using it. So you should inspect your code and find out how you actually display the PDF and ask your question related to that procedure.

Comment: Do you mean that you need to get the coordinates of text? If so, check this similar post: https://www.codeproject.com/Answers/1154832/iTextsharp-get-a-text-coordinates-from-existing-pd#answer1

Comment: I think he wants to allow user to draw annotation on pdf, so he is trying to get the co-ordinates so that the annotation can be drawn on pdf